# Oracle: control access to data through views?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a problem with controling access to data in a database. The data is a mix of price-data from my company and price-data bought from a data-provider and since they charge per user who can access their data I need to be able to limit the access to data.

I have a scheme "DATA" which holds all price-data. I am thinking having 2 additional schemes (example: LIM_ACCESS and FULL_ACCESS) with VIEWS that is build on the DATA-scheme. example:

```
CREATE VIEW LIM_ACCESS.V_PRICES AS<br>
SELECT [] FROM DATA.PRICES<br>
WHERE SOURCE = [MyCompany]

CREATE VIEW FULL_ACCESS.V_PRICES AS<br>
SELECT [] FROM DATA.PRICES
```

But to my experience then the LIM_ACCESS- and FULL_ACCESS-schemes has to have select-privelige on the DATA-tables to create the views and then I am back to square 1.

Being a novice in databases I feel there must be a relative simple solution to this so any advice or hint(if this question has been asked and answered before) is appreciated :-)

Kind Regards,
Svend

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions - they have been very helpfull :-) Have a great weekend :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the views in your DATA schema. Then `GRANT SELECT` on them to other schemas as necessary, ideally via database roles as Woot4Moo suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a view will not prevent a subset of users from accessing the data.  What you need to do is implement row level security.

Another approach is to use some form of role based permissions, that enable only the specific group of users you want to access the "paid" information.  This can be done fairly trivially example follows.

```
create user foo  
identified by password;
```

--no permissions

```
create role paid_data;
```

--grant privileges here  for the `paid_data` role

```
grant paid_data to foo
```

User `foo` will now have the permissions that the `paid_data` role has.  The advantage of using roles like this is that you can quickly revoke everyone's access that is in that group / add more accesses as they need to be incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

As GriffeyDog suggested, this is the best way to do it. First create two views in your schema and then grant select on those views to the two users.

```
CREATE VIEW LIM_ACCESS_V_PRICES AS<br>
SELECT [] FROM DATA.PRICES<br>
WHERE SOURCE = [MyCompany];

GRANT SELECT ON LIM_ACCESS_V_PRICES TO LIM_ACCESS;

CREATE VIEW FULL_ACCESS_V_PRICES AS<br>
SELECT [] FROM DATA.PRICES;

GRANT SELECT ON FULL_ACCESS_V_PRICES TO FULL_ACCESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use Oracle [Row Level Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_securing_data.htm#TDPSG30035) otherwise known as Oracle Label Security. I've used this to greatly simplify my application design while ensuring users only see the data they're allowed to see.